# Anaconda and Python3 Library Not Loaded on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, ipython, anaconda

Recently I installed Anaconda to get IPython to work on my Macbook pro. Prior to that I had Python3 and Python 2.7 installed with vitualenvwrapper configured and working successfully.

Having used IPython for awhile, today I went to create a new virtual environment for a Flask project.

When I run `python`, I get

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/selfishman/anaconda3/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

The same error appears when I try to create a new virtualenv. What can I do to fix my original Python3 installation and retain a working IPython and Anaconda at the same time?

P.S. When I run `python3`, I arrive in interactive console, as always.

Comment: What happens when you type `which conda` and `which python`?

Comment: Which conda returns the standard path to Anaconda and which python returns the path to Python 2.7 which came with the Mac.